# Mapping a widget template to a user control in SiteFinity 5

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-5

(Crossposted in [SiteFinity's forums](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity/developing-with-sitefinity/mapping-a-widget-template-to-a-user-control-in-sitefinity-5.aspx))

I'm using SiteFinity 5.0.  I created a custom module, using the module builder, called Promos.  It's content type is called Promo.

Next, I created a new widget template called PromoFlexSpace.  I basically copied the auto-generated template for a single Promo display and changed it a bit.

What I would like to do is globally map this widget template to a user control, so that any time that template is selected, it actually uses my user control.  I've found how to do this for an individual item:
http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/designer-s-guide/widget-templates/using-external-widget-template-file 
http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-05-10/mapping_external_templates_for_sitefinity_4_widgets.aspx

And I found something that came close to explaining what I'm trying to do on a global level:
http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-07-26/customizing_sitefinity_4_controls_with_the_viewmap.aspx

But I haven't found a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do yet (apologies if that last link actually does explain it - I need a better breakdown if it does).

What I've tried so far is going into the advanced settings > controls > view map and adding an entry there, but I can't find a value for HostType that works.

Comment: Update:  The 2nd solution in the 2nd post works, but I would love to not have a user control named OpenAccessDataProvider,D0CC1EB5DA984B4482009C69AAF3A2D5.ascx.  :)

Still interested in a solution that involves using the View Map.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Administration > Settings > Advanced > Toolboxes > ... > [Your Widget Control] there's a setting for "LayoutTemplate" where you can enter a path to an .ascx file.